# Inverting Op Amp LM324

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I am new to electrical design. I am experimenting with op-amps on LTspice, I cannot seem to figure out why my output signal is smaller than my input. I chose Rf to be 10k and Rin as 1k. The gain should be 10. [image]Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your circuit requires a **V-** DC supply, as well as the **V+** DC supply that you've applied.

Comment: LM324 is not rail-to-rail; see my related answer about LM741 (which has the same issue) here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/481184/35022

Answer (score 3):

You need to bias the op-amp so that the input is within the common-mode range and the output can swing about a center point. One way is to use a bipolar supply.

Also note that the reactance of the 1nF capacitor at 1kHz is Xc = \$\frac{1}{2 \pi f C}\$ ~= 160K ohms which will dominate over the 1K resistor, and result in |gain| << 1 anyway.

Here are two circuits which will amplify a 1kHz signal by -10. The first uses a negative supply. The second biases the output to about +1.3V but uses a single 3.3V supply. I used a 1.3V bias rather than 3.3V/2 because the input common mode range and output swing of the LM324 include ground but fizzle out close to the positive rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpNevS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think that I don't fully understand what the gain does because I would've expected the signal's amplitude at Vout1 to be 10x greater due to the gain.

Comment: Both of my circuits have a gain of -10. My input is 100mV. Much more and the op-amp output will saturate,

Answer (score 2):

Read the datasheet.

1. While some of the charts extend below 5 V, the datasheet tables do not characterize this part for 3.3 V operation.  For what you are trying to do, start with bipolar supplies of something like +/-15 V and see how that affects the output.  Then reduce them to +/-5 V and see the difference.
2. Once you have things working "normally", then change to a single supply and see what happens.
3. NOTE - While the negative power supply pin on this part (and its sister LM358) is labeled GND. this is a stupid mistake on National Semiconductor's part, trying to emphasize that the part is designed to handle single-supply operation.  But internally it still is a bipolar opamp.

Answer (score 2):

Several things are going on:

1. that capacitor is tiny, and forms a high pass filter with a freq = 1/(2 pi 1e-6) = 159 kHz. That's blocking your 1 khz input signal. You actually don't need that capacitor since your input has no DC bias (that capacitor normally just blocks DC and lets the AC through - but you have no DC to block)
2. Like glen_geek said in the comment, your voltage supply to the op amp is 0 to 3.3 V.  The (AC coupled) input is a -1 V to 1 V sine wave, and you have a 10x gain negative feedback amplifier circuit.  Even you had a dc coupled circuit, you'd get a 10 V to -10 V sine wave output, that would clip it at least between 0 and 3.3 V, resulting in a really distorted wave. It's even worse, because the op amp can't produce "rail to rail," that is it can't even reach 3.3 V or 0 V.